# Keep Chromecast CAF receiver alive after sender disconnect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I have a custom cast receiver that shows some text on the screen.  I want the receiver to stay active even after the sender disconnects (eg. the cast is initiated by a Chrome browser and then the user closes the browser).  What happens now is the receiver stays active for about 15 seconds and then closes.

I've tried using setInactivityTimeout in the following way but it doesn't seem to do anything.

`cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance().setInactivityTimeout(Number.MAX_VALUE);`

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior is to shut down the receiver app once the sender is disconnected, unfortunately.

I'm not sure this'll help, but when I was having this issue I found that the receiver media state would switch to `idle`, which caused a default timeout on the receiver that couldn't be stopped via the `setInactivityTimeout` call above (I imagine there might be a second timeout called that can't be altered?).

As a hack-y workaround, try loading non-existent media on your receiver, something like:

```
window.setInterval(() => {
   const message = new cast.framework.messages.LoadRequestData();
   message.media.contentId = 'https://example.com/fake/z00123.pic-o-me.jpg';
   playerManager.load(message)
   .then(() => {
   }).catch((err) => {
     return;
   });
}, 90000);
```

The timeout normally occurs after ~5 minutes from last change that I've seen, but I've had issues with that time-frame, so I shorten mine down to 1 1/2 minutes (as seen above).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a heartbeat message between the sender and the receiver. If that message times out, then typically the receiver will close itself.